# How to resolve error message "There was an issue looking up your account. Tap Next to try again." on Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

We added Windows Azure AD authentication SAML into our ASP.NET application for a few years now. Our Azure AD has the application registrations, our web.config has been configured, etc. The setup is a bit old but it has been working for a few years now.

**THE PROBLEM**

However, just recently whenever we are redirected to the login page on Microsoft, we get the error 'There was an issue looking up your account. Tap Next to try again.'

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I can't find any further information on this error [trying to enable diagnostics (in the little bottom-right popup with the correlation ID, trace ID) tell me 'something went wrong'].

I thought maybe it had do to with the passwords, but I've verified the credential use is working (directly logging into portal.azure.com is fine). And the error happens for ALL credentials.

I do know that Microsoft Azure recently changed the AD app registrations, but I've tried re-creating a new registration, and I still get the same error.

Lastly, oddly enough, our applications that are using OAuth 2.0 work.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the domain for the WS-Fed Endpoint has changed from sts.windows.net to login.microsoftonline.com . Changing the address in our web.config finally got this resolved.